# Program terminates in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a class project and have been working on this code all day, the logic seems to compile in the IDE but when I run it, it just hangs and then terminates. I have tried closing and opening the IDE and even created new projects, but i can't seem to solve this issue. I am using eclipse. here is the code.

```java
package assignment_One;
public class Weight_Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // a class that represents a Weight in pounds and ounces
        class Weight {
           // private instance variables
           private int pounds;
           private double ounces;
           // a private named constant that defines the number of ounces in a pound
           private double ouncesInPounds = 16;
           
           // constructor that allows the pounds and ounces to be initialized 
           // to the values supplied as parameters
           public Weight(int pounds, double ounces) {
               this.pounds = pounds;
               this.ounces = ounces;
               // normalize the ounces
               normalizeOunces();
           
        } 
           // a method that checks if the current object's weight is less than 
           // the object passed as a parameter to the method
           public boolean lessThan(Weight wt) {
               // return true if the pounds of the current object is less
               if(this.pounds < wt.pounds) 
                   return true;
               // return false if the pounds of the current object is more
               else if(this.pounds > wt.pounds)
                   return false;
               // else both the weights have the same pounds
               else {
                   // return true if the ounces of the current object is less
                   if(this.ounces < wt.ounces)
                       return true;
                   // return false if the ounces of the current object is more
                   else
                       return false;
               }
           }
           // a method that adds weight to the current object
           public void addTo(Weight wt) {
               // add the pounds and ounces of the called object to the current object
               this.pounds += wt.pounds;
               this.ounces += wt.ounces;
               // normalize the ounces
               normalizeOunces();
           }
           // a method that returns the string representation of the object
           public String toString() {
               return pounds + " lbs " + String.format("%.2f", ounces) + " oz";
           }
           // a method that returns the total number of ounces in the called object
           private double toOunces() {
               return pounds * ouncesInPounds + ounces;
           }
           // a method that normalizes the weight on which it was invoked
           private void normalizeOunces() {
               // loop until the no. of ounces is less than the no. of ounces in a pound
               while(ounces > ouncesInPounds) {
                   // decrement 16 ounces from the ounces and increment pound by 1
                   ounces -= ouncesInPounds;
                   pounds++;
               }
           }
           // I'm adding an additional method named getAvg()
           // this method will accept a number and divide the current object's weight
           // by the given number & then normalize the weight
           public void getAvg(int n) {
               // convert the current object's weight to total ounces
               ounces = toOunces();
               // reinitialize the current object's pound to 0
               pounds = 0;
               // divide the total ounces by the given number
               ounces = ounces / n;
               // normalize the ounces
               normalizeOunces();
           }
        }
        //public class Project1.java;
        class Project1 {
           // a method that returns the smallest weight among 3 weights
           public static final String java = null;
        private static Weight findMinimum(Weight w1, Weight w2, Weight w3) {
               // if the first weight is smaller than the second & third weight
               if(w1.lessThan(w2) && w1.lessThan(w3))
                   // return the first weight as the smallest weight
                   return w1;
               // else if the second weight is smaller than the first & third weight
               else if(w2.lessThan(w1) && w2.lessThan(w3))
                   // return the second weight as the smallest weight
                   return w2;
               // else the third weight is smaller than the first & second weight
               else
                   // return the third weight as the smallest weight
                   return w3;
           }
           // a method that returns the highest weight among 3 weights
           private static Weight findMaximum(Weight w1, Weight w2, Weight w3) {
               // if the first weight is greater than the second & third weight
               if(!w1.lessThan(w2) && !w1.lessThan(w3))
                   // return the first weight as the highest weight
                   return w1;
               // else if the second weight is greater than the first & third weight
               else if(!w2.lessThan(w1) && !w2.lessThan(w3))
                   // return the second weight as the highest weight
                   return w2;
               // else the third weight is greater than the first & second weight
               else
                   // return the third weight as the highest weight
                   return w3;
           }
           // a method that returns the average weight among 3 weights
           private static Weight findAverage(Weight w1, Weight w2, Weight w3) {
               // create a new Weight object
               Weight wt = new Weight(0, 0);
               // add the weight of the three objects to the new Weight object
               // by invoking the addTo() method
               wt.addTo(w1);
               wt.addTo(w2);
               wt.addTo(w3);
               // invoke the getAvg() method to get the average weight
               wt.getAvg(3);
               // return the average weight
               return wt;
           }
           // main method
           @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
        } {
               // create three weight objects
               Weight weight1 = new Weight(25, 20);
               Weight weight2 = new Weight(30, 8);
               Weight weight3 = new Weight(23, 10);
               // display the 3 weights
               System.out.println("Weight 1: "+weight1.toString());
               System.out.println("Weight 2: "+weight2.toString());
               System.out.println("Weight 3: "+weight3.toString());
               // invoke the findMinimum() method to get the smallest weight among the 3 weights
               Weight min = findMinimum(weight1, weight2, weight3);
               // display the minimum of the 3 weights
               System.out.println("\nMinimum weight: "+min.toString());
               
               // invoke the findMaximum() method to get the highest weight among the 3 weights
               Weight max = findMaximum(weight1, weight2, weight3);
               // display the maximum of the 3 weights
               System.out.println("\nMaximum weight: "+max.toString());
               
               // invoke the findAverage() method to get the average weight of the 3 weights
               Weight avg = findAverage(weight1, weight2, weight3);
               // display the average of the 3 weights
               System.out.println("\nAverage weight: "+avg.toString());
           }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two main methods?

Comment: one main method is empty. Fix your code and the indentation

Comment: Your main method is **empty**, it is immediately followed by an instance initializer, which probably should have been the body of your main method. Also the nesting and indentation of your code seems off.

Comment: You define a class inside a main method.  How can that work?  Readability matters.  You should fix that before you go on.  Lots and lots of code for a very simple idea.  Too much code.

Comment: You have put a `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` on that last `main` method - Eclipse is correct, you are not using that method so your code is not doing what you expect.

Comment: do you really want the `class Weight` declared inside the `main` method? That is very unusual... same for having a second `main` method... same for both `main` methods being empty (do nothing)... || first of all I would recommend to NOT use nested classes - specially NOT inside a method!

Comment: As you are using Eclipse, you can "Debug" the program instead of "Run". Set a breakpoint to the first line of your main() method, and then single-step through your code, watching what it does instead of just being puzzled.

Comment: Learning how to debug a program that doesn't work as expected is just as important as writing the program itself (but a topic often neglected in courses).

Comment: @user16320675 I left that for the OP to recognize themself...

Comment: Also, don't whittle ounces down. Instead, do it in one step: `normalizeOunces() { pounds += ounces / ouncesInPounds * ouncesInPounds; ounces %= ouncesInPounds; }`

Answer (score 2):

To show the root problem, see the structure of your code - most statements and comments removed to facilitate visualization:

```java
public class Weight_Class {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        class Weight {
            // MEMBERS DELETED
        }

        class Project1 {
            // MEMBERS DELETED

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public static void main(final String[] args) {
                // NO STATEMENTS
            }
            
            {
                // create three weight objects
                Weight weight1 = new Weight(25, 20);
                Weight weight2 = new Weight(30, 8);
                Weight weight3 = new Weight(23, 10);
                ...                
                System.out.println("\nAverage weight: "+avg.toString());
            }
        } 

        // NO STATEMENTS  
    }
}
```

We can now see that there are NO STATEMENTS inside either `main` methods. The statements after the `// create three weight objects` are **not** inside any `main` method, but are in an Instance Initializer block!

Much probably you want something similar to the following structure

```java
public class Weight_Class {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create three weight objects
        Weight weight1 = new Weight(25, 20);
        Weight weight2 = new Weight(30, 8);
        Weight weight3 = new Weight(23, 10);
        ...                
        System.out.println("\nAverage weight: "+avg.toString());

    }
    
    static class Weight {
        // MEMBERS DELETED
    }
    
    static class Project1 {
        // MEMBERS DELETED
        
        // NO main METHOD HERE
    } 
}
```

Obs 1: added `static` to nested (inner) classes so they do not require a containing class.

<sub>Obs 2: posted codes are intended to show the overall structure and are NOT complete - they will not compile!</sub>